# How to highlight a new added entry in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, highlighting

I've created a DB application in MVC 4 using EntityFramework. It works okay, however I couldn't find the way of highlighting new added item to my table(html). Is it possible to highlight new rows in DB applications in MVC? Like in C#:

```
DataGrid.SelectedItem
```

Any advice or help would be very clarifying. How to highlight a row in MVC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How are you rendering the table?

One option is to use [TempData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.webviewpage.tempdata%28v=vs.108%29.aspx). Store the identifier of the added item in TempData and check for the identifier when rendering the table.

ItemController:

```
// POST: /Item/Create
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include="Id,Name")] Item item)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Items.Add(item);
        db.SaveChanges();

        TempData["AddedItemId"] = item.Id;
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(item);
}
```

Item view:

```
<!-- Views\Item\Index.cshtml -->
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        var className = "";

        if (TempData["AddedItemId"] != null && (int)TempData["AddedItemId"] == item.Id)
        {
            className = "alert-info";
        }
        <tr class="@className">
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```